# Could not resolve a binding for http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I am using apache cxf + spring, the stuff runs in eclipse but not in command line. keep get the error could not resolve binding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solution :

1. step1: using maven shade plugin
2. step2: if you are using spring with cxf, making sure add following to your @Configuration class

   @ImportResource( { "classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml", "classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension http.xml", "classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" } )

or

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-http.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />
```

big credit to

http://www.java-allandsundry.com/2011/01/orgapachecxfservicefactoryserviceconstr.html