# ServiceConstructionException when creating a CXF web service client (scala+java+wsdl2java)

Tags: java, web-services, gradle, soap, cxf

These other questions hint at a solution but I haven't been able to get this to work:
[Could not resolve a binding for http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26159206/could-not-resolve-a-binding-for-http-schemas-xmlsoap-org-wsdl-soap)
[ServiceConstructionException when creating a CXF web service client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006185/serviceconstructionexception-when-creating-a-cxf-web-service-client)
[How to package an Apache CXF application into a monolithic JAR with the Maven "shade" plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831954/how-to-package-an-apache-cxf-application-into-a-monolithic-jar-with-the-maven-s)

When I start my application by doing `java -Xdebug -jar myapp.jar` I'm getting a `ServiceConstructionException: Could not resolve a binding for null` when the app makes a SOAP call. The app and the SOAP call works just fine when I start the application in IntelliJ. Here is a minimal example reproducing the error: https://github.com/stianlagstad/mainclass-and-jxf-problems-demo

Steps to reproduce:
- `gradle clean build && java -Xdebug -jar build/libs/mainclass-and-jxf-problems-demo.jar`
- Go to http://localhost:4242/endpoint/ and see the error

Can anyone help me figure out which changes I have to do to make the SOAP call work?

Edit to provide more information:

If I edit `build.gradle` to not exclude META-INF (i.e. having `configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }` instead of `configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it).matching{exclude{it.path.contains('META-INF')}} }`) I get this error instead: `Error: Could not find or load main class com.shadowjarcxfproblem.JettyLauncher` (when starting the app as a jar). Starting the app in IntelliJ still works however, and the SOAP call works then as well.

The stacktrace for the cxf error:

```
org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Could not resolve a binding for null
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createBindingInfo(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:352)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpointInfo(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:259)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:144)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientFactoryBean.create(ClientFactoryBean.java:91)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxyFactoryBean.create(ClientProxyFactoryBean.java:157)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create(JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.java:142)
    at com.shadowjarcxfproblem.SoapServiceFactory.create(SoapServiceFactory.java:36)
    at com.shadowjarcxfproblem.service.CalculatorServiceComponent$CalculatorServiceImpl.<init>(CalculatorService.scala:17)
...
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.BusException: No binding factory for namespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/ registered.
    at org.apache.cxf.bus.managers.BindingFactoryManagerImpl.getBindingFactory(BindingFactoryManagerImpl.java:93)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createBindingInfo(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:339)
    ... 75 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading these two and trying a bunch of different things I finally stumbled upon something that works!
[How to package an Apache CXF application into a monolithic JAR with the Maven "shade" plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831954/how-to-package-an-apache-cxf-application-into-a-monolithic-jar-with-the-maven-s?noredirect=1&lq=1)
https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-use-the-gradle-shadow-plugin-to-merge-spring-handlers-and-spring-schemas-files-of-multiple-spring-jar-dependencies/6713/6

Using the gradle shadowjar plugin with this task solved the problem:

```
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.transformers.ServiceFileTransformer
shadowJar {
    // Make sure the cxf service files are handled correctly so that the SOAP services work.
    // Ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45005287/serviceconstructionexception-when-creating-a-cxf-web-service-client-scalajava
    transform(ServiceFileTransformer) {
        path = 'META-INF/cxf'
        include 'bus-extensions.txt'
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, i am getting same problem, i tried adding above code snippets to my build file but not working, can you help pls??

Comment: If you create a reproducible example and put it on GitHub I might be able to help :)

Comment: I do have a liferay dxp workspace let me know if you are familiar with liferay i can share the repository.